# Isolation within the same transaction

Tags: database, transactions, rdbms, isolation-level

I've always considered that there were no isolation within a single transaction.

For example if I have 2 methods M1 and M2, M1 update X in database and M2 select X or a set containing X.
If both method belongs to the same transaction and M2 is executed after M1:

- Does M2 always seen M1 update whatever the type of operation, the RDBMS or the isolation level is ?
- If no, can someone explain in details the different possible behavior according to associated criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the situation described, M2 will always see M1's changes yes. An isolation level of READ COMMITTED, for example, only applies to *other* transactions, not the transaction supplying it.

Cheers -

Comment: Thx for answering guy (+1) Don't take it personally but i'd like to wait for some additional views before accepting your answer (I was convinced of this behavior also but this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947979/data-are-not-visible-at-support-transation-block#20948112 made me doubt)

Comment: No problem! You might try the DBA Stack Exchange site - it's mostly developers here and we're not usually experts at this level...it's http://dba.stackexchange.com/